# Bootstrap without jQuery in vue.js (webpack)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I just started using Vue.js, but not sure how to add Boostrap package without using jQuery. I don't want to mix jQuery and Vue.js, so I decided to write my own JS code for triggering modal dialog (e.g.).

This is my prefered package:

`npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta`

Currently, the app returns an error (jQuery is required), and I know that installing jQuery and adding it in `webpack` config would fix the problem, but as I said, I'd like to avoid jQuery.

Yes, I know that there's [boostrap-vue](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue), but I'm not interested into that too.

Thanks,
N.

Comment: You simply [cannot use Bootstrap without jQuery](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start). What's the problem with including it?

Comment: @Phil I don't want to mix jQuery and Vue.js. I could also add React, Angula, Ember and so on.. I found interesting discussion here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23204 It looks that jQuery will be rewritten with vanilla JS, but not so fast. Anyway, I could fork Bootstrap and remove dependencies. Just curious if there's other solution..

Comment: Bootstrap JS is primarily a bunch of jQuery plugins so no, there is not another way (without using a Bootstrap clone like bootstrap-vue). Again, what's the problem with including jQuery? It will not conflict with Vue. They solve separate problems

Comment: Bootstrap is dependent on jQuery. Just don't use jQuery in your code?

Answer (score 2):

You can

`yarn add bootstrap@4` or `npm install bootstrap@4 --save`

Then in .scss

`@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

or in .js

`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

This will include css only (things like modal transitions will need custom implementation).